# Error when using overloaded operator () C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

Here is a C++ code, it is simple, but I get error which I don't understand.
I don't know how else to use overloaded `operator ()`, but the way I did.
Program should do the following.

> Type your word: Programming
>   n: 5
>   P
>   Pr
>   Pro
>   Prog
>   Progr

Error I get:

> no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << Word::operator()(int)(n)'

Word.h

```
#ifndef WORD_H
#define WORD_H


class Word
            {
            private:
                    char *str;
            public:
                    Word();
                    ~Word();
                    Word operator()(int); //overloading operator ()
                    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,Word&);
                    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,Word&);
            };

#endif
```

Word.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Word.h"

Word::Word()
    {
    str=new char[100];
    }

Word::~Word()
    {
    delete[] str;
    }


Word Word::operator()(int d)  //overloading operator ()
    {
    Word pom;
    strncpy(pom.str,str,d);
    return pom;
    }


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,Word& s)
    {    
    out<<s.str; return out;
    }


std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,Word& s)
    {
    in>>s.str; return in;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Word.h"


int main()
{
   Word r;
   std::cout<<"Type your word: "; 
   std::cin>>r;

   int n;
   std::cout<<"n:"; 
   std::cin>>n;

   for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) std::cout << r(i) << std::endl; //error when using r(i)
}
```

Comment: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,Word& s)` should be `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const Word& s)`

Comment: Thank you. Still not working...

Comment: Changed the `friend` declaration accordingly? `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const Word&);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this

```
cout << r(i);
```

the compiler does the following:

- Creates a temporary variable of type `Word`
- Calls `operator(int)`, and captures its result
- Stores the result in a temporary object
- Passes the temporary object to `operator <<`

Since you have no access to the temporary object, the compiler disallows non-constant access to it. That is why you get the error: you are trying to pass an object that is implicitly constant to a parameter that takes a non-constant reference.

To fix this, change the signature of your `operator<<` to the canonical one, i.e. taking a `const` reference for the `Word&` parameter:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Word&);
//                                             ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the signature of

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,Word& s);
```

This accepts a `Word` by reference.

```
Word operator()(int);
```

returns a `Word` by value. In the expression

```
cout << r(i);
```

you end up trying to bind a temporary value to a reference, which is forbidden by the language. Only a `reference to const` can bind to a temporary value. Change your `operator<<` signature (in the declaration and definition) to:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Word& s);
```

and it should work. This is also a sensible choice, since `operator<<` should not change the `Word` argument.